# How can you control a DC motor over I2C?

Tags: motor, pwm, dc-motor, i2c, motor-controller

I would like to control a [small DC motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BF9JVJQV) via I2C.  My first thought was to use an H-bridge-like [DC motor driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/drv8210) with a PWM input, and then find an I2C PWM generator to drive the H-bridge.

However, aside from LED lighting and self-programmed PICs, it seems difficult to find an I2C PWM generator.  I've not measured the motor's max load yet, so maybe an [I2C constant-current LED driver](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kinetic-Technologies/KTD2027EWE-TR?qs=lc2O%252BfHJPVba64R2ZzIo3g%3D%3D) really is the way to go if the current is small enough... but maybe not for brushed reactive loads?

**Question:** What is the "proper" way to drive a small 6V DC motor controlled over an I2C bus?

[image: 6V tiny motor]

Comment: What do you mean by difficult to find? Find in general, find a suitable, or find one that is available for purchase? PCA9685 modules and similar exist for hobbyists, will they work?

Comment: Or motor drivers like DRV8830. It looks like an Arduino is also a very popular use case, or any other MCU of course. Note that I2C is a short-distance network, which begs the question: if you have an I2C host already (typically another MCU), why not just get one with enough IOs to generate PWM directly?

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for the part reference, that could work.  We don't need very much distance, but the motors are on a rotating platform so we need a rotary slip ring and wish to minimize the wire count.  We already need i2c on the rotating part for sensors, and 5V can drive the motor, so an i2c motor driver and the 4 i2c wires is enough to get the job done.  Otherwise we would have to send motor PWM _and_ i2c through the slip ring which puts us at 8 wires minimum and the slip ring starts to get big

Comment: The small DC motors I have used over the years typically have a control loop that runs between 1k and 2k Hz (1k mostly).  I would question whether or not an IIC PWM generator could be updated at that rate, much less the time between the control loop determining a new PWM rate vs. the time the IIC PWM generator receives the new rate.  Personally, I would recommend running the extra wires for the PWM signal and encoder signals to ensure good closed loop control of the motor.